# How to groupby and drop rows that include "-inf" or "inf" and all the previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`, I want to groupby "group" and drop 1) not only rows that include `NaN`, but all the preceding values or 2) rows that precede the last `NaN`.

```
group  date     value    
  1    jan2019    NaN
  1    jan2019    3
  1    jan2019    NaN
  1    feb2019    3        
  1    mar2019    4       
  1    mar2019    5        
  2    feb2019    0        
  2    feb2019    NaN       
  2    mar2019    7        
  2    mar2019    4        
  2    apr2019    5
```

desired df version 1.

```
group  date     value    
  1    feb2019    3        
  1    mar2019    4       
  1    mar2019    5                  
  2    mar2019    7        
  2    mar2019    4        
  2    apr2019    5
```

desired df version 2.

```
group  date     value    
  1    jan2019    NaN
  1    feb2019    3        
  1    mar2019    4       
  1    mar2019    5        
  2    feb2019    NaN            
  2    mar2019    7        
  2    mar2019    4        
  2    apr2019    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flag the inf values using `abs`+`eq`. Then to flag all the values before it as well, you can reverse the order of the Series and use `cummax`. Since you want to do this job across groups, you can use `groupby.cummax`. Finally, use the boolean mask to filter the desired output via `loc`:

```py
out = df.loc[~df['value'].abs().eq(float('inf'))[::-1].groupby(df['group']).cummax()]
```

If the values to flag are NaNs (rather than inf), then we could use `isna` instead:

```py
out = df.loc[~df['value'].isna()[::-1].groupby(df['group']).cummax()]
```

Output:

```py
   group     date  value
2      1  feb2019    3.0
3      1  mar2019    4.0
4      1  mar2019    5.0
7      2  mar2019    7.0
8      2  mar2019    4.0
9      2  apr2019    5.0
```

For the third output, you can use `groupby.shift`:

```py
out = df.loc[(~df['value'].isna()[::-1].groupby(df['group']).cummax()).groupby(df['group']).shift().fillna(True)]
```

Output:

```py
    group     date  value
2       1  jan2019    NaN
3       1  feb2019    3.0
4       1  mar2019    4.0
5       1  mar2019    5.0
7       2  feb2019    NaN
8       2  mar2019    7.0
9       2  mar2019    4.0
10      2  apr2019    5.0
```

Comment: I edited my OP. I used your code replacing 'inf' with 'NaN' but those rows still appear?

Comment: @Olive so it's actually NaN, not inf?

Comment: thanks i needed both, this is great. one additional question: if i want to drop all the preceding values but not the last "NaN"?

Answer (score 0):

A more verbose but possibly more readable approach. `.isin` will work for NaN as well as infs.

```
def filter_preceding(df, search_values=[np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]):        
    ind = np.where(df['values'].isin(search_values))[0]
    if len(ind) == 0:
        return df
    max_ind = ind.max()
    return df.iloc[max_ind + 1:, :]

df.groupby('group').apply(filter_preceding).reset_index(drop=True)
```